# Error when launching a default Meteor application

Tags: meteor

I have started getting errors when I launch a brand new default Meteor app.

$ meteor --version
   Meteor 1.2

Here are my steps to reproduce on Mac OS 10.10.5:

1. Reboot the computer, open a Terminal window and run...
2. $ meteor create test
3. $ cd test
4. $ meteor
5. Open a browser window at http://localhost:3000

Server error:

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
Internal exception while processing message { msg: 'connect',
  version: '1',
  support: [ '1', 'pre2', 'pre1' ] } Cannot read property '_CurrentInvocation' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property '_CurrentInvocation' of undefined
    at withoutInvocation (packages/meteor/packages/meteor.js:404:1)
    at bindAndCatch (packages/meteor/packages/meteor.js:414:1)
    at Object._.extend.setInterval (packages/meteor/packages/meteor.js:441:1)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startHeartbeatIntervalTimer (packages/ddp-common/packages/ddp-common.js:71:1)
    at [object Object]._.extend.start (packages/ddp-common/packages/ddp-common.js:66:1)
    at new Session (livedata_server.js:312:20)
    at [object Object]._.extend._handleConnect (livedata_server.js:1427:29)
    at livedata_server.js:1356:18
```

Browser error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_CurrentInvocation' of undefinedwithoutInvocation @ meteor.js:407bindAndCatch @ meteor.js:417_.extend.setInterval @ meteor.js:444_.extend._startHeartbeatIntervalTimer @ ddp-common.js:71_.extend.start @ ddp-common.js:66_.extend._livedata_connected @ ddp-client.js:4158onMessage @ ddp-client.js:3310(anonymous function) @ ddp-client.js:2704_.each._.forEach @ underscore.js:134_.extend._launchConnection.self.socket.onmessage @ ddp-client.js:2703REventTarget.dispatchEvent @ ddp-client.js:143SockJS._dispatchMessage @ ddp-client.js:1128SockJS._didMessage @ ddp-client.js:1186SockJS.websocket.that.ws.onmessage @ ddp-client.js:1333
meteor.js:862 Received error from server:  Must connect first
meteor.js:864 For:  Object {msg: "sub", id: "ARDnnLu2X7G7WfWgx", name: "meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions", params: Array[0]}id: "ARDnnLu2X7G7WfWgx"msg: "sub"name: "meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions"params: Array[0]length: 0__proto__: Array[0]__proto__: Object
```

The app seems to run normally. What does this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `meteor update` to update Meteor to version `1.2.0.1`.

Read more about this [error](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5228).

Comment: The error went away when I ran `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`. It appears that this error appeared around 10 hours ago. I didn't explicitly install Meteor 1.2. Does this mean that the latest version of Meteor is downloaded from the source each time `meteor create ...` is run?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Maybe your `.meteor/release` file contained `METEOR@1.2`?